# Split by last space including tab space in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as follows

```
Esophageal have not 45.3
The end is nigh 23
Maybe (just) (maybe>32) 45.2
```

Every line ends in a number (both with and without decimal points)
I want to split the line before the last number

I have tried this regex:

```
    myarray[]=null;
    myarray=match.split("/\\s+(?=\\S*+$)/");
```

but it doesn't split it

Comment: Remove the regex delimiters. Use `"\\s+(?=\\S*+$)"`. See [demo](http://ideone.com/gdVDPZ).

Comment: don't try to split, try to match (use the matches or find method with capture groups).

Comment: What is the exact output you are waiting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
String Str = "Maybe (just) (maybe>32) 45.2"; 

for (String retval: Str.split("\\s(?=\\b(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)$)")){
   System.out.println(retval);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/cWwO8k)**

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string and get the last value of array:

```
    String[] array = "Maybe (just) (maybe>32) 45.2".split(" ");
    String firstPart = array[0];
    String lastPart = array[array.length-1];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        firstPart += " " + array[i]; 
    }

    System.out.println(firstPart);
    System.out.println(lastPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match.split("[ \\t](?=[.\\d]+([\\n\\r]+|$))");
```

Results should look like:

```
Esophageal have not
45.3 The end is nigh
23 Maybe (just) (maybe>32)
45.2
```